# Selenium can't seem to click on an href link

Tags: python, selenium, hyperlink

```
<a class="page-link" title="Next page" data-page-number="3" href="/recruiter/smartsearch?searchHistoryId=1702735186&amp;searchCacheKey=1fdcde45-657b-4666-824a-12ab561b3a91%2Cm9d5&amp;searchRequestId=d371cf7e-2703-43de-9fe5-218fad50e152%2C5wG7&amp;searchSessionId=1702735186&amp;linkContext=Controller%3AsmartSearch%2CAction%3Asearch%2CID%3A1702735186&amp;doExplain=false&amp;start=50" rel="next">
   <svg aria-hidden="true">
       use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#chevron-right-icon" data-size="small"></use></svg><span class="hide-a11y">Go to page 3</span></a>
```

I'm using a call to

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a[title="Next page"]').click()
```

but this returns an empty string

Comment: Please read  [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking more questions.

Comment: How clicking link could return you empty (or not empty) string? What exactly you want your script to do? Describe your problem with more details (add exception log)

Answer (score 0):

Try using xpath

```
//a[@title='Next page']
```

Comment: Is there any reason to use this XPath instead of exactly the same CSS selector?